# Capture Pubsub Failures in Apache Beam - Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I have one apache beam dataflow job written in java. That job reads some data flow DB and modify the result and publish that to pubsub

`DB -> Update Object -> Publish`

I want to capture the failure records while publishing in pubsub and write it to a separate file.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think about catching errors in the dead letter queue in the pipeline before calling the write method from `PubSubIO`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate this

Comment: You can catch elements in the pipeline code instead of in the `PubSubIO` via `TupleTags` and `try catch`, I also created a library to simpliy this. if you want I can propose you a solution in this direction.

Comment: Yes Please... Could you please share the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently functionality to capture records that fail to be published to PubsubIO.Write. What sorts of failures would you like to fail permanently (vs being retried)?

Comment: We are trying to retry the failed records. If that retry is failed again we are trying to capture in a Cloud storage as file and process them later. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `catch` all the errors from the code of the `pipeline` with `TupleTags` and `try catch` blocs on `transformations`.

Then you will have 2 sinks :

- The good sink
- The bad sink

I created a library called `Asgarde` to simplify `error handling` with `Beam` :

https://github.com/tosun-si/asgarde

You can install this lib in your project with `Maven` (this version is linked to Beam 2.41.0) :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.groupbees</groupId>
    <artifactId>asgarde</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or Gradle :

```
implementation group: 'fr.groupbees', name: 'asgarde', version: '0.20.0'
```

An example of usage in the pipeline :

```java
// Input PCollection
final PCollection<String> wordPCollection....

final WithFailures.Result<PCollection<Integer>, Failure> resultComposer = CollectionComposer.of(wordPCollection)
        .apply("Map", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via((String word) -> word + "Test"))
        .apply("FlatMap", FlatMapElements
                .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                .via((String line) -> Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(line.split(" "), 1, 5))))
        .apply("ParDo", MapElementFn.into(TypeDescriptors.integers()).via(word -> 1 / word.length()))
        .getResult();

// Good output PCollection
PCollection<String> output = result.output();

// Bad failure PCollection
PCollection<Failure> failures = result.failures();
```

`CollectionComposer` proposed by `Asgarde` is created from a `PCollection` and behind the scene, each `apply` uses `TupleTags` and `try catch` bloc.

`CollectionComposer` returns a `Result` structure and from this, we can recover the `output` and `failure` `PCollection`

Your failure sink can be written to `Bigquery` `GCS` or other (dead letter queue).

You can also use native `Beam` if your prefer, you can check an example from my `Github` repository :

https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-java-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/src/main/java/fr/groupbees/domain_ptransform/TeamStatsTransform.java

Comment: @sweety have you tested my solution ?